# Where is defined <package_name> in class import 'package:<package_name>/...?

Tags: flutter

I try to migrate a project.
I have problem with import that is not resolved and auto import from code desn't work.

```
 import 'package:<package_name>/...
```

I thought that <package_name> was defined in pubspec.yaml:

```
name: <package_name>
description: A new Flutter project.
```

but it doesn't work.
Is there elsewhere or something else?
Thank you!